# HHVM on ISPConfig failing to bind port 80

Tags: apache, debian, hhvm

I am running ISPConfig under Debian 7 with HHVM 2.4.1

I do not really understand how to run HHVM.
I did install it, `hhvm -version` works.

I want to run hhvm **only** on a **specific** domain of my dedicated server (located in `/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web` - ISPConfig equivalent of the traditional /www/ folder ).

I did not write any ProxyPass line because I don't get why there are 2 kinds of tutorial on the facebook/hhvm wiki : One about hhvm and one about hhvm-fastcgi... The first one doesn't need ProxyPass unlike the the second one... (I only have hhvm)

I tried using this command line

```
/opt/dev/hhvm/hphp/hhvm/hhvm -m server
```

It generates

```
Fail to bind port 80
Fail to bind port 80
Fail to bind port 80
```

And when I do it with apache off (stop command), it shows warning in cycles...

```
HipHop Warning: Case insensitive constant names are not supported in HipHop in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 20
```

Comment: HHVM server support is going to be discontinued. It is best if you run HHVM on another port (i.e. 9000), and use apache/nginx fastcgi to pass the request to hhvm.

Answer (score 2):

Check this one out 
http://blog.noczone.com/?p=102

it will help you to integrate HHVM into ISPConfig hopefully